# iPad hairdryer trick

Tags: ipad

My iPad didn't charge after a complete battery drain, so I tried the hairdryer trick and it worked, but after a few hours it unfortunately automatically turned off again. Is there a permanent fix for this or do I have to do the hairdryer trick every time?

Comment: Hairdryer trick?

Comment: Yeah, use a hairdryer to warm up the back of your iPad for 30 seconds and it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess a new battery would be a better long-term fix.

Comment: I'd add more, but there isn't any more.